# How does ServiceContractGenerator generate namespaces

Tags: c#, wcf

I am trying to use ServiceContractGenerator to generate a web service client in C# from a wsdl. I am new to this class. I am using the code pretty much as it appears in the example on Microsoft's site and what I have read from the web. When I run Svcutil.exe on the wsdl, I get all the types in the same namespace in the C# code. When I use ServiceContractGenerator, It puts the client code in the namespace I specify, but it creates a second namespace for the wsdl types. The wsdl has a section like this:

```
<wsdl:types><xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/Imports"><xsd:import schemaLocation="http://devabntstapp10.psohealth.local/TZ_TCS_SERVICES/AdminService.svc?xsd=xsd0" namespace="http://tempuri.org/"/><xsd:import schemaLocation="http://yyy/zzz/AdminService.svc?xsd=xsd2" namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/zzz.Correspondence"/><xsd:import schemaLocation="http:/yyy/zzz/AdminService.svc?xsd=xsd1" namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/"/></xsd:schema></wsdl:types>
```

There is a message defined as

```
<wsdl:message name="ICorrespondenceAdmin_ListOwners_InputMessage"><wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:ListOwners"/></wsdl:message>
```

The code I am using is

```
   generator = new ServiceContractGenerator();
    try {
        generator.NamespaceMappings.Add("*", "WebServiceClients");
    }
    catch (Exception) {
    }

    MetadataExchangeClient mexClient =
        new MetadataExchangeClient(
            new Uri(uri),
            MetadataExchangeClientMode.HttpGet);

    mexClient.ResolveMetadataReferences = true;
    MetadataSet metaDocs = mexClient.GetMetadata();

    WsdlImporter importer = new WsdlImporter(metaDocs);

    System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<ContractDescription> contracts
      = importer.ImportAllContracts();
    ServiceEndpointCollection eps = importer.ImportAllEndpoints();
    foreach (ContractDescription contract in contracts) {
        generator.GenerateServiceContractType(contract);
    }


    if (generator.Errors.Count != 0)
        throw new Exception("There were errors during code compilation.");

    StringWriter stringWriter =
        new StringWriter(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
    System.CodeDom.Compiler.IndentedTextWriter textWriter
        = new System.CodeDom.Compiler.IndentedTextWriter(stringWriter);

    codeDomProvider.GenerateCodeFromCompileUnit(
        generator.TargetCompileUnit,
        textWriter,
        options);


    textWriter.Close();
```

I get a namespace of WebServicesclients for the client class CorrespondenceAdminClient and a namespace of zzz.Correspondence for all the parameters and return types. Svcutil puts them all in WebServicesclients. I seem to be missing something.

Answer (score 3):

You probably need to redefine the XmlImportOptions and the XsdDataContracts, all types are not generated by the xsdDataContracts, I guess the generateServiceContract only change the namespace for this one.

```
        importer.State.Remove(typeof(XsdDataContractImporter));
        var xsdDCImporter = new XsdDataContractImporter();
        xsdDCImporter.Options = new ImportOptions();
        xsdDCImporter.Options.Namespaces.Add("*", nameSpace);
        importer.State.Add(typeof(XsdDataContractImporter), xsdDCImporter);

        var xmlOptions = new XmlSerializerImportOptions(xsdDCImporter.CodeCompileUnit);
        xmlOptions.ClrNamespace = nameSpace;
        importer.State.Add(typeof(XmlSerializerImportOptions), xmlOptions);

        System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<ContractDescription> contracts = importer.ImportAllContracts();
```